# play part of an audio file in Java

Tags: java, audio

is it possible to play a part of an audio file in Java? I know the starting time and end time and I want to play the period in between.
Searched for it a little but got no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java Media Framwork (JMF). Take a look on this link to see simple example: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/java-example-very-simple

Then take a look on the API of Player:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Player.html

It has method `addController()`. One of avaliable controllers is Clock:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/j
avax/media/Clock.html#setMediaTime(javax.media.Time)

It has methods `setMediaTime()` and `setStopTime()` that you need.

Comment: Hi AlexR, thanks for the reply. I already made it work. Now I got a very wierd Problem, don't know if you have met this: the two methods works perfectly on my mac but the same code won't get the same result on windows. although the stop time is set right, the player plays a while after that. do  you have any solutions for this??

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Java Sound package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/sound/) because it's part of the stock Java distribution, and I find it easier to use than JMF.  The [Java Sound info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) gives a nice example that should get you started.

Comment: I don't like the extra library either but I found no methods i could use in java sound package.